# Find if two game object overlapping - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve if two objects (let's say two cubes) with their locations and dimensions.
for example we have a function:

```
def isOverlapped(locationCube1, dimensionCube1, locationCube2, dimensionCube2)
```

It should return true if they overlapped and false otherwise. The parameters should be a tuple of x, y, z coordination.

For example: we have two cubes:
Cube 1: location = (2, 2, 2) , dimension = (1.0, 5.0, 1.0)
Cube 2: location = (1.0, -1.0, 1.0) , dimension = (2.0, 2.0, 2.0)
So, after I put this in simulation I found out that they overlapped each others.

Now, I am wondering how to program such a thing. Thank you!

Comment: Those two solids do not overlap.  They are separated by one unit in the Y axis.  What told you they did?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795709/checking-whether-two-rectangles-overlap-in-python-using-two-bottom-left-corners) where they present a solution in the 2d case. It shouldn't be too hard to generalize to the 3d case.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you check each axis separately.  If ANY axis does not overlap, then the objects do not intersect.  Assuming the lines are sorted, if the end of line 1 > start of line 2 and start of line 1 < end of line 2, then they overlap.

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169